# Netbeans can't find sources in non-standard maven project layout

Tags: maven, netbeans, netbeans-8, netbeans-8.1

I'm trying to use Netbeans 8.1 to work on a Maven project with a non-standard project structure. In my project, my sources are under **`src/foo`** instead of **`src/main/java`**. To open my project, I click *File* > *Open Project...* in the menu. Then I navigate to my project in the file browser that opens. Then I select my project and click *Open*. When my project opens in the Netbeans *Projects* tab, it does not contain any source packages. It only shows a folder labeled *Dependencies* and a folder labeled *Project Files*.

I've tried changing the location of the source folder in the project properties to fix this. I right-click on the project, click *Properties*, and then click *Sources* in the menu on the left. Then I try to edit the *Source Folder* value, but the value isn't editable. It's worth noting that for `ant` projects, I can add sources in the project properties, but for Maven this doesn't seem possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your maven project actually build correctly? The IDE will pull the source location from your POM model. Eg.

```
<project>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/foo</sourceDirectory>
  </build>
```

Comment: Interesting, my project does build correctly, but it's not really my project so I'm not sure why. I think I need to understand the project more, but your solution works great.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to change your project so that it uses [Maven's standard directory layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html). One very easy way to do that (if you have your sources under one directory), is to create symbolic link from **`src/main/java`** to **`src/foo`**:

```
    mkdir src/main && ln -s /path/to/project/src/foo src/main/java
```

If you do that, Netbeans will be able to see your sources, and you can keep your non-standard directory structure.

**Possible Alternative:** When searching for alternative solutions to this issue, I found that I could import the project into Netbeans as either a *Java Project with Existing Sources* or a *Java Free-Form Project* (I'm not sure which one I used). However, Netbeans won't let me do that anymore, so I'm not sure if it will always work and I'm not sure of the steps I took. If you want to try that solution, click *File* > *New Project*, choose the *Java* category, and choose either *Java Project with Existing Sources* or *Java Free-Form Project*. In the next window, point Netbeans to your existing sources as the location of the project. As I said above, I'm sure that this worked for me once, but I cannot use this method anymore as Netbeans shows the following error:

> Project folder is managed by a project foo-project-name. Instead of creating a new project just open it. If by a chance you just deleted the project foo-project-name than [sic] restart the IDE to reuse the folder.